Convert IFormCollection to NameValueCollection
I am trying to port .net3.1 code to .net8 class library where I have below code
private static void ReadForm(Dictionary<string, GatewayParameter> gatewayParameterList)
{
    NameValueCollection form = HttpContext.Request.Form;
    foreach (string item in form.AllKeys)
    {
        SetGatewayParameterValue(gatewayParameterList, item, form[item], HttpMethod.Post);
    }
}

But I am getting below error;

Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormCollection' to 'System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I know that HttpContext.Request.Form returns NameValueCollection but then why this error?

ASP.NET Core never returned a NameValueCollection. Are you migrating from .NET Framework?

Yes, Initial code is in ASP.NET.

ASP.NET Core is completely different. You can't just copy the old code over. HttpContext itself is no longer a singleton for example. Creating a strongly typed object from form values is supported out of the box using Model Binding. In fact, Form values have the highest priority

ASP.NET Core's HttpRequest.Form doesn't return a NameValueCollection, it returns an IFormCollection since .NET Core 1.0. You probably confused this with .NET Framework's HttpRequest.Form property.
IFormCollection implements IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<>> which means you can iterate over it instead of trying to access items through AllKeys :
var form = HttpContext.Request.Form;
foreach (var (key,value) in form)
{
    SetGatewayParameterValue(gatewayParameterList, key, value, HttpMethod.Post);
}


Thanks for pointing me out to the right direction.
